# jquery ui Dialog default position

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

i have customized my dialog by adding maximize,restore and minimize button, the only problem i'm stuck with is when default a new dialog is created it automatically calculates to position the dialog on the screen , at this point i want to know the position of where it is created , infact i can see in chrome developer tools the exact position, but i'm not able to retrieve the same value in the html nor the js file.

The reason why i want this value is ,when a dialog is created and on maximizing it and restoring it ,it gets restored to a default position like top:5px,left:10px; but i am sucessfully able to restore it back to the same position after the dialog is dragged onto some point.

The position is calculated exactly to through the above _position function. is there any way that you can paa the value calculated here to a html file??

Kindly help me on this, been stuck with it through ages.

Cheers Jeev